# HorizontalTree problems Internet Explorer

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I use Primefaces 5.1 with JSF 2.2.6.

When i create one horizontal tree in primefaces and need view this in Internet Explorer 11 have problems with design drawing of the tree. The tree appears incomplete without lines between nodes.
In others browsers the tree is drawn perfectly.

why? 
solutions?